# Optimizing ajax request for a large data set

Tags: ajax, laravel

Need some help with a ajax use case.
I need to render a graph on a data that has a size of 45 MB approx, I am sending a ajax request on button click to get that data from server and then render the graph on the client side based upon the response.

The problem is due to the content size Content Downloading time is so long which is around 23s. I need to optimize it to around 5s.

Can anyone recommend a solution for this use case?

I have attached the timing stats of the ajax request.
[AJAX REQUEST STATS IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7A2K.png)

Here is the ajax function

```
<script>

    function generateGraph() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/test",
            success: function (data) {
                var records = data;
                console.log(records.length);
                var x = records[0];
                var y = records[1];
                Plotly.addTraces('myDiv', [
                    {
                        x: x,
                        y: records[1],
                        type: 'scattergl',
                        mode: "line"
                    },
                    {
                        x: x,
                        y: records[2],
                        type: 'scattergl',
                        mode: "line"
                    },
                    {
                        x: x,
                        y: records[3],
                        type: 'scattergl',
                        mode: "line"
                    }, {
                        x: x,
                        y: records[4],
                        type: 'scattergl',
                        mode: "line"
                    }, {
                        x: x,
                        y: records[5],
                        type: 'scattergl',
                        mode: "line"
                    }, {
                        x: x,
                        y: records[6],
                        type: 'scattergl',
                        mode: "line"
                    }, {
                        x: x,
                        y: records[7],
                        type: 'scattergl'
                    }, {
                        x: x,
                        y: records[3],
                        type: 'scattergl',
                        mode: "line"
                    }, {
                        x: x,
                        y: records[8],
                        type: 'scattergl',
                        mode: "line"
                    }, {
                        x: x,
                        y: records[9],
                        type: 'scattergl',
                        mode: "line"
                    }, {
                        x: x,
                        y: records[10],
                        type: 'scattergl',
                        mode: "line"
                    }, {
                        x: x,
                        y: records[11],
                        type: 'scattergl',
                        mode: "line"
                    }, {
                        x: x,
                        y: records[12],
                        type: 'scattergl',
                        mode: "line"
                    }, {
                        x: x,
                        y: records[13],
                        type: 'scattergl',
                        mode: "line"
                    }, {
                        x: x,
                        y: records[14],
                        type: 'scattergl',
                        mode: "line"
                    }, {
                        x: x,
                        y: records[15],
                        type: 'scattergl',
                        mode: "line"
                    },
                    {
                        x: x,
                        y: records[16],
                        type: 'scattergl',
                        mode: "line"
                    },
                    {
                        x: x,
                        y: records[17],
                        type: 'scattergl',
                        mode: "line"
                    },
                    {
                        x: x,
                        y: records[18],
                        type: 'scattergl',
                        mode: "line"
                    }
                ]);

            }
        });
    }

    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [{type: 'scattergl'}], {});
</script>
```

Comment: please put your code(ajax as well as controller and query too) too so that we can understand where things taking time.

Comment: @GauravGupta just added the ajax function, please note that no queries are running on the server side. I have calculated the server processing time which is only around 2s.

Comment: didn't get your problem but i think one thing that you should change in-spite of putting every single index of array make it dynamic by using loop.

Comment: also how much time it take to get result from server ?

Comment: use cache on your js and css so that it wan't take time again and again so same things

Comment: @GauravGupta, I have attached the request stats as well. There is no issue with server side nor with client js. The only issue is the data size that makes the ajax request to make it completed.

Comment: there only one ajax code is written above, In which there is no data  added at the time of request , and as per your above comments  you are getting response very quickly then which thing have size of 25 mb and taking 23 sec?

Comment: Server is sending the response to ajax request in 2s only. The response size is 43 mb as its a large dataset. After the ajax received the response its taking 23s to download that content. I hope you got the point now

Comment: just one more thing download that content ?? are you downloading some file or you mean load content like big images take time to show ?

Comment: Download Content means, the time it takes to travel from server to client. Its just a data not any images

Comment: how much time server take to make that data ? also if there is no query as you mention early then how do you get that data.

Comment: I am getting a data from a file which exists on the server